# performancedrops after redrawing scene multiple times, memory seems ok

Tags: three.js, webgl

I have some bad isssues with the framerate going down heavily after redrawing a scene multiple times dynamically and I hope someone can help. In previous Three versions I noticed as well the memory leaking, this seems fine in the actual version. I dont know why the performance can go down if memory stays ok and  cpu as well.

My application is triggered completley by ajax calls, that draw canvasas in different div containers. By initializing webgl in a new container the old container gets cleaned.

The basic functionality is like in following code. if you push the button lets say 20 times, you will see the framerates dropping:

http://jsfiddle.net/crizzis/YuJj6/

```
<input type="button" value="activate rendering in Div1" onclick="init_webgl(1);"></input>
<div id="webgl_container_1" onclick="init_webgl(1);" style="top:0px; height:300px; border:1px solid blue"></div>    
<input type="button" value="activate rendering in Div2" onclick="init_webgl(2);"></input>
<div id="webgl_container_2" onclick="init_webgl(2);"style="top:500px;height:300px; border:1px solid red"></div>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var camera, fov=70, controls, scene, projector, renderer, container;
        var time=0;
        //init_webgl(1);

        function init_webgl(styleId) {  

            console.log('writing webgl canvas to div with style Id: webgl_container_'+styleId);

            if (scene!=null){
                destroyWebGl();
            }   

            container = document.getElementById('webgl_container_'+styleId);    

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( fov, container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight, 1, 10000 );
            camera.setViewOffset( container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight, 0, 0, container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight );
            camera.position.z = 350;                
            scene.add(camera);              

            projector = new THREE.Projector();

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);

            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
            light.position.set( 0.31,0.5, 1 );
            scene.add( light )              

            parent = new THREE.Object3D();
            scene.add( parent );                        

            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            console.log('webgl initialized');
            init_renderObjects();
        }            

        function init_renderObjects(){                  
            for (var x = 0; x < 400; x++){
                var cube = new THREE.Mesh( 
                 new THREE.CubeGeometry( 50, 50, 50 ),
                 new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { ambient: 0xffffff, color: 0xffffff, opacity: 0.58,specular: 0xffffff, shininess: 40, shading: THREE.SmoothShading,  transparent: true,  wireframe: false } )
                );      
                cube.position.x = 100*x;
                parent.add( cube );
            }                
            animate();
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            timedelta=Date.now()-time;
            time = Date.now();          

            var children = parent.children;
            for(var i = children.length-1;i>=0;i--){
                var child = children[i];
                child.rotation.y = child.rotation.y+timedelta*0.005;
            };              
            render();
        }           

        function render() {             
            if (renderer!=null)renderer.render( scene, camera );                
        }

        function destroyWebGl(){              
             console.log( "destroyWebGl");
             console.log( "before programs"+ renderer.info.memory.programs );
             console.log( "before geometries"+ renderer.info.memory.geometries );
             console.log( "before textures"+ renderer.info.memory.textures );            

            var children = parent.children;
            for(var i = children.length-1;i>=0;i--){
                var child = children[i];
                child.geometry.dispose();
                child.material.dispose();
                parent.remove(child);
            };  

            scene.remove(parent);
            //renderer.deallocateObject( parent );

            camera = null;
            controls= null; 
            scene=null;
            projector=null;  
            parent=null;                    

            container.removeChild( renderer.domElement );       
            container=null;

            console.log( "after programs:" + renderer.info.memory.programs );
            console.log( "after geometries" + renderer.info.memory.geometries );
            console.log( "after textures" + renderer.info.memory.textures );              

            renderer=null;
            console.log('finished destroy');
        }            
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `init_webgl` function calls `animate()` which means the animation loop is not cleared and it is reinitialized each time the button is pressed. After 20 clicks you are running 20 animation loops.

You only need to call `animate()` once at the start of your program and remove it from button click code.